# Are there any open-source code-generation projects out there?

Tags: open-source, code-generation

I'm using an in-house code generator in which we supply all the metadata regarding our objects, and it generates our database, and object model including validation logic. Once we load all the data in the database, we use classic ASP <% %> to build our templates. I would like to know what open-source frameworks similar to this that are out there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check openArchitectureWare (http://www.openarchitectureware.org/) which is Eclipse-based.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [mygeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/)? It's not exactly open source but it's free, and the scripts are totally open. The most common usage is to generate the data layer given a database schema, but you can be more creative than that.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/), which allows you to run Python scripts inside of source files.  The included Cog module allows printing into the file that it's currently working on.  Cog is licensed under MIT.

Comment: i like the way cog works to generate code.. but I could not get it to work.. it needs some module called 'path' which unfortunately am not able to find. Could you help me with setting up this cog machine... I'd really love to have it up my sleeve :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Star UML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) it's open source and has some decent code generation capabilities.

I'd also look into Eclipse Plug-in options, I'm sure they're available I just haven't worked with any.

Answer (score 1):

[MyGeneration Code Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/) is now Open Source.